Overlay PNG over video does not work if I try to add fade in, but works without fadein
I have this code:
ffmpeg   -i out.mp4 -i "C:\Users\josesevilla\Pictures\Logo_OAG_fondo_transparente.png" -filter_complex "[1:v] scale=iw*0.2:ih*0.2 [logo];[0:v][logo] overlay=(main_w - overlay_w)/2: main_h*2/3:enable='gte(t,35)'" outoverlay4.mp4.

It produces a video in which de PNG logo is overlayed in the 35th second in a 40 s long video, up to the end.

as you can see, both the footage and the image are valid.
Now I want to add a fade-in effect and I try this other code:
ffmpeg   -i out.mp4 -i "C:\Users\josesevilla\Pictures\Logo_OAG_fondo_transparente.png" -filter_complex "[1:v] scale=iw*0.2:ih*0.2, fade=t=in:st=35:d=3:alpha=1 [logo];[0:v][logo] overlay=(main_w - overlay_w)/2: main_h*2/3-overlay_h/2:enable='between(t,35,40)'" outoverlay5.mp4


and no logo appears.
I have tried multiple combinations with enable='gte()' and enable='between()' to no avail. I have also attempt with the filter enabled at 30 s, with other combinations as well, but to no avail. Fade in is not working. Only if I set alpha to 0 I can see teh "hole" or silhouette from the "enabled" set time, but no fade applied at all.
I have also tried to change the approach and apply the solution proposed in ffmpeg overlay image with fade in and fade out
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -loop 1 -t 3 -i "C:\Users\josesevilla\Pictures\Logo_OAG_fondo_transparente.png" -filter_complex "[1:v] scale=iw*0.2:ih*0.2,fade=t=in:st=5:d=3:alpha=1[logo];[0:v][logo]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2"  output5.mp4

and others like FFmpeg: Adding multiple overlays to the video with the fade in/out effect. Command works but the images ( overlays ) doesn't show in the video and blank video with external picture and fade in effect but still cannot get it to work
¿Any ideas?
the ffmpeg version:
ffmpeg version 2024-05-13-git-37db0454e4-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)

I found a solution that works for me. I caught it at https://superuser.com/questions/567059/ffmpeg-fade-in-watermark-only/1842780#1842780
I finally have this command:
ffmpeg   -i video_de_encadenamiento_de_fases_con_texto.mp4 -loop 1 -i Logo_OAG_fondo_transparente.png -filter_complex "[1:0] format=rgba,scale=iw0.4:ih0.4,fade=in:st=37:d=3:alpha=1[logo];[0:0][logo] overlay=(main_w - overlay_w)/2: main_h*2/3-overlay_h/2" -t 40 -y video_de_encadenamiento_de_fases_con_texto_logo_final.mp4

I found a solution that works for me. I caught it at https://superuser.com/questions/567059/ffmpeg-fade-in-watermark-only/1842780#1842780
I finally have this command:
ffmpeg   -i video_de_encadenamiento_de_fases_con_texto.mp4 -loop 1 -i Logo_OAG_fondo_transparente.png -filter_complex "[1:0] format=rgba,scale=iw*0.4:ih*0.4,fade=in:st=37:d=3:alpha=1[logo];[0:0][logo] overlay=(main_w - overlay_w)/2: main_h*2/3-overlay_h/2" -t 40 -y video_de_encadenamiento_de_fases_con_texto_logo_final.mp4

here is the video https://vimeo.com/948386845?share=copy
